# Picker works on Android but not on Windows

Tags: c#, android, .net, windows, maui

I am working on .NET 8 with MAUI to create a cross-platform application, and I am creating a Picker, when I run it on an Android device the picker works fine, but when I run it on my Windows machine the picker does not work.

Este es el codigo del picker

```
<Picker Title="Seleccione una Opcion" 
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Bodegas}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBodega}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Nombre}"
        TextColor="Black"
        FontSize="18"
        HeightRequest="50"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

I'm trying with this code but not works on windows.

Comment: I tested the code you provided and this was caused by the `HeightRequest="50"`. You can not set the height too small and this will not make the picker work well.

Answer (score 1):

What is not working is the *display* of `SelectedItem` in Windows, however the Picker is otherwise functional.

What is causing it is your `HeightRequest="50"`. If you remove this item, it will display fine (or if you make the value larger). The reason it displays in Android is really a coincidence. If you lower the `HeightRequest` value even more, the same issue will occur in Android.

I would avoid a `HeightRequest` altogether and change the Picker's size by changing the `FontSize`. Or tune these two values together.